# Calculating mean absolute percentage error between values in 2 dictionaries in python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I have a dictionary of locations, and then property-value pairs, as so:

```
{"Russia": 
    {"/location/statistical_region/size_of_armed_forces": 65700.0,
     "/location/statistical_region/gni_per_capita_in_ppp_dollars": 42530.0, 
     "/location/statistical_region/gdp_nominal": 1736050505050.0,
     "/location/statistical_region/foreign_direct_investment_net_inflows": 8683048195.0, 
     "/location/statistical_region/life_expectancy": 80.929, ...
```

And so on, for every country.

And then a dictionary containing a single array, each value in the array is a dictionary with 3 keys:

```
{
    "sentences": [
        {
            "location-value-pair": {
                "Russia": 6.1
            }, 
            "parsedSentence": "On Tuesday , the Federal State Statistics Service -LRB- Rosstat -RRB- reported that consumer price inflation in LOCATION_SLOT hit a historic post-Soviet period low of NUMBER_SLOT percent in 2011 , citing final data .", 
            "sentence": "On Tuesday , the Federal State Statistics Service -LRB- Rosstat -RRB- reported that consumer price inflation in Russia hit a historic post-Soviet period low of 6.1 percent in 2011 , citing final data ."
        }, 
        {
            "location-value-pair": {
                "Russia": 8.8
            }, 
            "parsedSentence": "In 2010 , annual inflation in LOCATION_SLOT hit NUMBER_SLOT percent due to the summer drought , exceeding forecasts and equalling the figure for 2009 , the year of the global financial meltdown .", 
            "sentence": "In 2010 , annual inflation in Russia hit 8.8 percent due to the summer drought , exceeding forecasts and equalling the figure for 2009 , the year of the global financial meltdown ."
        }, ...
```

What I want to do is compare for each sentence, and for each location and value in that sentence, calculate the closest matching values that match that location-value pair in the first dictionary, and then return the top statistical property it corresponds to and add it as a new key for the sentence dictionary.

For example:

For sentence 1, I see that we are looking at Russia and a value of 6.1. I want to index into the first dictionary, find "Russia", and go through all values that exist e.g. 65700.0,42530.0,1736050505050.0,8683048195.0. I then want to find the mean absolute error for each property e.g. 23% for the size_of_armed_forces value, 10% for the gni_per_capita property etc. I then want to find the smallest one let's say and add it as a key to the second dictionary, so:

```
{
                "location-value-pair": {
                    "Russia": 6.1
                }, 
                "predictedRegion": "/location/statistical_region/gni_in_ppp_dollars"
                "meanabserror": 2%
                "parsedSentence": "On Tuesday , the Federal State Statistics Service -LRB- Rosstat -RRB- reported that consumer price inflation in LOCATION_SLOT hit a historic post-Soviet period low of NUMBER_SLOT percent in 2011 , citing final data .", 
                "sentence": "On Tuesday , the Federal State Statistics Service -LRB- Rosstat -RRB- reported that consumer price inflation in Russia hit a historic post-Soviet period low of 6.1 percent in 2011 , citing final data ."
            },
```

My confusion when thinking of writing this is simply how to access the key values for another dictionary as a condition for another dictionary. My current thinking is:

```
def predictRegion(sentenceArray,trueDict):

    absPercentageErrors = {}

    for location, property2value in trueDict.items():
        print location
        absPercentageErrors['location'] = {}
        for property,trueValue in property2value.iteritems():
            print property
            absError = abs(sentenceArray['sentences']['location-value-pair'].key() - trueValue)
            absPercentageErrors['location']['property'] = absError/numpy.abs(trueValue)

    for index, dataTriples in enumerate(sentenceArray["sentences"]):
        for location, trueValue in dataTriples['location-value-pair'].items():
            print location
```

However obviously I cannot access `sentenceArray['sentences']['location-value-pair'].key()` in this line: `absError = abs(sentenceArray['sentences']['location-value-pair'].key() - trueValue)` because it is outside of the loop.

How can I get access to this key from a loop referring to a totally different variable?

Comment: You missed the *minimum* part in [Minimum, Complete, and Verifable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. You posted such a large dictionary that all values of "Russia" have been cut off and so it's impossible to quite understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: The first dict I posted was as an example (only 1 country), but I have amended it to be Russia not Canada to make more clear.

Comment: Please amend it further so that you show **the actual numbers you are using in your example.** You use `[23, 421, 24, 412]` but i do not see those anywhere

Comment: Sure, now done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for.

```
countries = {'Canada': {'a': 10, 'b': 150, 'c': 1000},
             'Russia': {'d': 9, 'e': 5, 'f': 1e5}}
sentences = [
        {"location-value-pair": {"Russia": 6.1}, 
         "parsedSentence": "bob loblaw", 
         "sentence": "lobs law bomb"
        }, 
        {"location-value-pair": {"Russia": 8.8}, 
            "parsedSentence": "some sentence", 
            "sentence": "lorem ipsum test"
        }]


def absError(numer,denom):
    return abs(numer-denom)/float(denom)

def findMatch(target, country):
    return min(country, key= lambda x: absError(target, country.get(x)))

def update(sentence):
    (c,target), = sentence.get("location-value-pair").items()
    country = countries[c]
    matched = findMatch(target,country)
    error = absError(target, country.get(matched))
    res = sentence.copy()
    res.update({'predictedRegion': matched, 'meanabserror': "{:.2f}%".format(100*error)})
    return res

updated = [update(sentence) for sentence in sentences]    
updated
```

Outputs:

```
[{'location-value-pair': {'Russia': 6.1},
  'meanabserror': '22.00%',
  'parsedSentence': 'bob loblaw',
  'predictedRegion': 'e',
  'sentence': 'lobs law bomb'},
 {'location-value-pair': {'Russia': 8.8},
  'meanabserror': '2.22%',
  'parsedSentence': 'some sentence',
  'predictedRegion': 'd',
  'sentence': 'lorem ipsum test'}]
```

Comment: You, good sir, are a true hero. I have now also learnt to not place in `...` into my input sentences like the plague. The use of `lambda` etc is new to me, thank you for showing me this!